# Реализация многозадачности. Написание соей ОС на Си и NASM;

Tags: c, многопоточность, ос, nasm

Пишу свою ОС.

Пытаюсь реализовать многозадачность и псевдомногопоточность.

Но не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

Имеются *void* функции на СИ с ассемблерными вставками (в частности часть из них требует переход в защищенный режим ядра)

**Задача**: запустить выполнения void функции на время, после её приостановить, выполнить немного 2ю, 3ю, ... 10ю void функции по очереди и приостановить их. Вернуться к  первой функции.

Comment: Код выполняется в RealTime режиме

Comment: Запускаете таймер и устанавливаете обработчик прерываний. Создаете контексты всех функций. Запускаете функцию. При возникновении прерывания сохраняете ее контекст. Вызываете следующую (если она уже была запущена), то вызвращаетесь в ее сохраненный контекст. И т.д.

Comment: @avp Есть ли где про это подробно написано?
А то боюсь что-то упустить

Comment: Вам надо почитать про устройство ОС "изнутри". Структуры ее данных и т.п. Подробно написано? Не знаю, не помню. Принципы есть в любой книге по устройству ОС. Кое что написано в [Ядро Linux. Описание процесса разработки](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/17925734/). Код линукса найти в сети не проблема, но боюсь, разобраться в нем сходу не получится.

Comment: @avp уже 2ю неделю пытаюсь)

Comment: @avp спасибо за книгу - скачал - щас попробую прочитать и осмыслить

Comment: Успехов! Главное потом самому все это хорошо продумать (ну и документацию на процессор внимательно изучить)